# HTML DOM Document parsing

Tags: php, html, dom, domdocument

i am new to DOM Document..
i have this html:

```
    <tr class="calendar_row" data-eventid="39657">
        <td class="alt1 eventDate smallfont" align="center">Sun<div class="eventday_multiple">Dec 9</div></td>
        <td class="alt1 smallfont" align="center">3:34am</td>
        <td class="alt1 smallfont" align="center">USD</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="calendar_row" data-eventid="39658">
        <td class="alt1 eventDate smallfont" align="center">Sun<div class="eventday_multiple">Dec 10</div></td>
        <td class="alt1 smallfont" align="center">5:14am</td>
        <td class="alt1 smallfont" align="center">EUR</td>
    </tr>
```

i am trying to get first the contents inside the tr's using this code:

```
    $ret = array();
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true); 
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($html);
    //$doc->saveHTMLFile('textbox.php');

    $text = $doc->getElementsByTagName('tr');
    foreach ($text as $tag){
        $ret[] = $doc->saveHtml($tag); 
        echo $doc->saveHtml($tag); 
    }
```

i dont know why the value being echoed was the whole document and not the values inside the tr's..

second, i would like also to get the values in between those td tags like 5:14 AM,EUR,etc. but i dont have any idea how to do that.

Pardon for noob question..

Best Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc ->loadHTML("$html");
$tables = $doc->getElementsByTagName('table');
$table = $tables->item(0);//takes the first table in dom

foreach ($table->childNodes as $td) {
  if ($td->nodeName == 'td') {
    echo $td->nodeValue, "\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: see my edit ,if this also doesn't work then your $html may be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Passing an element to [`saveHtml`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php) generates the elements outerHTML not its innerHTML, so you get its tag attributes and all its content. Of course you need to be running PHP>=5.3.6 .

The values between the td can be obtained by `$td->firstChild->nodeValue;` or just `$td->textContent;` where `$td` is the `<td>` in question.

Comment: im sorry, how will i use $td->textContent;.. i dont know where to put it

Comment: @Vainglory07 you did't really what you wanted to do with it so I couldn't say how you would use it. If you don't know how to get the `<td>`s just use getElementsByTagName on the tr to find then.