# Parse HTML with PHP

Tags: php, html, parsing

I have a problem, I have to make a Parser of a Web page. The structure is as follows:

```
 <TABLE WIDTH=80%>

<tr><td colspan=7><BR><BR></td></tr>
<TR>
<Td colspan=7><FONT FACE="arial" align=left><B><A NAME="TEST">Anagrafica</B><br></TH>
</TR>
<tr><td colspan=7></td></tr>
<TR>
 <TH ALIGN=LEFT ><FONT COLOR="#AA0000" FACE="arial" SIZE="2">Name</FONT></TH>
  <TH></TH>
  <TH ALIGN=LEFT ><FONT COLOR="#AA0000" FACE="arial" SIZE="2">Surname</FONT></TH>
  <TH></TH>
  <TH ALIGN=LEFT ><FONT COLOR="#AA0000" FACE="arial" SIZE="2">ID</FONT></TH>
  <TH></TH>
 <TH ALIGN=LEFT ><FONT COLOR="#AA0000" FACE="arial" SIZE="2">Code</FONT></TH>
 </TR>

 <tr>
 <TD COLSPAN="7">
 <HR SIZE="1" NOSHADE></TD>
 <TR>

 <TR>
   <TD ALIGN="left" VALIGN="TOP" NOWRAP><FONT SIZE="1" FACE="arial">Mario</FONT>     </TD>
   <TD WIDTH="10"><VALIGN="TOP"><FONT SIZE="1" FACE="arial">&#160;</FONT></TD>
   <TD ALIGN="CENTER" VALIGN="TOP" NOWRAP><P ALIGN="CENTER"><FONT SIZE="1" FACE="arial"> Mario </FONT></TD>
   <TD WIDTH="10"><VALIGN="TOP"><FONT SIZE="1" FACE="arial">&#160;</FONT></TD>
   <TD ALIGN="LEFT" VALIGN="TOP" NOWRAP><FONT SIZE="1" FACE="arial">1</FONT></TD>
   <TD WIDTH="10"><VALIGN="TOP"><FONT SIZE="1" FACE="arial">a</FONT></TD>
   <TD ALIGN="LEFT" VALIGN="TOP" NOWRAP><FONT SIZE="1" FACE="arial">132</FONT></TD>

 <TR>
   <TD ALIGN="left" VALIGN="TOP" NOWRAP><FONT SIZE="1" FACE="arial">Mario</FONT>     </TD>
   <TD WIDTH="10"><VALIGN="TOP"><FONT SIZE="1" FACE="arial">&#160;</FONT></TD>
   <TD ALIGN="CENTER" VALIGN="TOP" NOWRAP><P ALIGN="CENTER"><FONT SIZE="1" FACE="arial"> Mario </FONT></TD>
   <TD WIDTH="10"><VALIGN="TOP"><FONT SIZE="1" FACE="arial">&#160;</FONT></TD>
   <TD ALIGN="LEFT" VALIGN="TOP" NOWRAP><FONT SIZE="1" FACE="arial">1</FONT></TD>
   <TD WIDTH="10"><VALIGN="TOP"><FONT SIZE="1" FACE="arial">a</FONT></TD>
   <TD ALIGN="LEFT" VALIGN="TOP" NOWRAP><FONT SIZE="1" FACE="arial">132</FONT></TD>

 <TR>
```

I want to take the data of the 4 columns using this script

```
$start = strpos($content,'<Td colspan=7><FONT FACE="arial" align=left><B><A NAME=');
if ($start == TRUE) {
    $end = strpos($content,'</TABLE>',$start) + 8;
    $table = substr($content,$start,$end-$start);
    preg_match_all("|<TD(.*)</TD>|U",$table,$rows);

    $x = 1;
    $counter = 1;
    echo "<table class=\"TFtable\">";
    foreach ($rows[0] as $row){
        if ((strpos($row,'<TR')===false)){
            preg_match_all("|<TD(.*)</TD>|U",$row,$cells);
            $status[$x] = strip_tags($cells[0][0]);
            $x = $x+1;
            $counter = $counter+1;
        }
        if ($counter % 7 == 1) {
            echo "<tr><td>{$status[2]} - {$status[4]} <br> {$status[6]} - {$status[1]}</td></tr>\n";
            $x = 1;
        }
    } 
    echo "</table>";
```

In this way, however, the last field $ status [1] I will appear in the second row as if indeed it were part of line 2:

example

Mario Rossi 1 213

Mario Bianchi 2 324

Displaying

Mario Rossi 1

Mario Bianchi 2 213

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Simple: Use [DOM](http://php.net/dom). You should NOT be manually parsing html

Comment: Obligatory: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1902010

Answer (score 1):

Try looking into [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) instead of regexing the HTML. With `loadHTML()` you can let PHP parse the HTML. Look at [HTML DOM Document parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13908212/html-dom-document-parsing) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

If you're actually trying to build a parser, you probably don't want to use a pre-built HTML/DOM parser. If this is the case, you'll probably want to follow these steps:

- tokenize your input (you can use regex for this part)
- process your tokens, determining each one's meaning as they come.

  - you might want to look into so-called "recursive descent parsers"
  - each token may change the meaning of the following token
  - you may need to look at the next token in line without processing it
- return your output, most likely in the form of an object that represents a DOM tree

You'll probably need to look into the formal definition of the language to determine what kinds of expressions may follow each other. For instance, the definition of a start tag likely looks something like the following (though this isn't a formal definition, and may contain errors):

`'<' + tagName + attributes list + '>'`

Again, this is probably wildly inaccurate, and you'll want to look into the formal definition of the language.

[The w3c HTML global structure document](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html) might be a good place to start.